# JMeter Asynchronous API calls

Tags: jmeter

The mobile app that I am testing with Jmeter makes 4 asynchronous API calls when logging in. Is there any way to simulate this with JMeter ?

Currently I can only get JMeter to make the calls synchronously, so when wrapping them all in the same transaction controller, the response time is the total of the 4 calls (instead of the highest one)

Many thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently JMeter doesn't offer a relevant test element, the easiest way of implementing your scenario is using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to perform nested asynchronous calls, something like:

[image: Groovy Ajax]

See [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) guide for more detailed explanation, code snippets,etc.

You can also consider [developing a custom sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/extending/jmeter_tutorial.pdf) with similar functionality and make it a part of your JMeter as a plugin or even share it with the community.

Comment: is it still a valid answer as of today or there are some news with jmeter about it? thanks

Comment: Now it is much easier to use [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter), no extra coding required, just add the Samplers you would like to run in parallel as children and that would be it. You can install Parallel Controller using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Parallel Controller in JMeter.

> All elements inside the Parallel Controller will be executed parallel to each other. This way, you will have one main flow and other flows with asynchronous requests, which will be executed in a parallel way.

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-load-test-async-requests-with-jmeter