# JMeter - Send Asynchronous requests dependent on timeout

Tags: asynchronous, jmeter, httprequest, jmeter-plugins, taurus

I have a Test plan with several HTTP request I want to reach a certain TPS.

Some request takes more than a few seconds, and I want to execute them in asynchronous way so I'll continue executing other request while waiting for response asynchronously (later to be checked)

Better yet (general case), I would like to have a time limit of 3 seconds wait, and if 3 seconds past to continue to next request

Is there a way to submit such scenario in JMeter? or other tool executing JMeter as Taurus or plugin?
I found similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33037277/jmeter-asynchronous-api-calls) but it's for all requests to be asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

1. With regards to `reach a certain TPS` you can go for [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin) combination. There is a possibility to connect them using [feedback function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/#Use-With-Throughput-Shaping-Timer-Feedback-Function) so JMeter will kick off extra threads in order to reach and maintain the target throughput.
2. With regards to `time limit` - you can define this 3 seconds timeout on "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) configuration element

   [image]

   the setting will be applied to all HTTP Request samplers in the HTTP Requests Defaults [scope](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules), this way you will get guarantee that under any circumstances your request will not last longer than 3 seconds as by default JMeter will wait for response infinitely.

Comment: 1. I don't want just **any** threads to be kick off, but specific requests that may take longer than expected/wanted   2. Adding timeout will fail request and/or won't wait for response